# The network connection was lost error only on iOS7 with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, nsurlconnection, afnetworking

I am using `AFNetworking 1.2` library in my app. When I have `iOS6` as a base SDK everything works fine, but if I change base SDK to `iOS7`, then receiving an error in some requests(not all) stating that - `"The network connection was lost".`

I am not able to find out the cause of the issue, also there is no pattern for this issue as all requests are not failing.

Is there something change in the iOS7 SDK which is causing this issue?

Comment: `AFNetworking 1.2` is not the latest version and there could be a bug. The latest `AFNetworking` library is `2.0.3`. Can you upgrade and see if that fixes your issue? Also, the latest version allows you to use `NSURLSession` which is Apple's recommended way forward.

Comment: If it was failing in all scenarios then I can understand then some problem with AFNetwork version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing issue for 2-3 days, found the root cause of the issue. In response header getting some field which sdk not able to handle.

Comment: Could you give examples of what kind of fields that could be, please? Or how to determine which fields might cause this error in my request.

Comment: For my case it is "Expires" which was causing issue.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, for iOS7, you'll want to upgrade to a newer version of [AFNetworking (2.x)](http://afnetworking.com)

Comment: That I can do, but my main concern is why it is failing for few calls only, while the structure is same for all.

Comment: All it takes are a 'few calls' to change between OS versions ;) Not to mention 2.x has support for NSURLSession which replaces NSURLConnection in functionality with iOS7+

Comment: What was the issue? I'm facing the same issue with random reports of lost connection